# How to use Java console in eclipse to change string

Tags: java, eclipse

Sorry that my title may be a little confusing. I am a little new to java and I am trying to write something so that when you run the code in eclipse, the console asks you for your email address, you input it and it changes email1 from:

`String email1 = "";`

To:

`String email1 = "personsemail@mail.com";`

Could someone tell me how to do this?

Here is my full code:

```
public class MainClass {

    public MainClass() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String email1 = "testemail1";
        String email2 = "testemail1";
        boolean isMatch;

        isMatch = email1.equals (email2);
        if (isMatch == true){
            System.out.println("Emails Match!");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Emails Dont Match");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Scanner#nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) method to read a line of text from console.

```
// System.in represents input stream
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

// print() not println()
System.out.print("Enter your email: ");

// Store email
String email1 = scanner.nextLine();

// close when done!
scanner.close();
```